# How do i read a csv file into a pandas dataframe which is stored in my local storage in jupyter lab

Tags: python, pandas, path, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

The following is my code to read my CSV file stored in my project folder into the pandas data frame in jupyter lab.

```
      df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\u s e r\my first project\news.csv")
      #Get shape and head
      df.shape
      df.head()
```

the below is the error I'm getting while doing so

```
            pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in 
            pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

            pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in 
            pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

            FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\u s e r\my first 
            project\news.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\u s e r\\my 
            first project\\news.csv'
```

I've tried using r subscript and saving the path in a variable .but nothing seems to be working.

what should I do?

Comment: Posting [images or links to code or errors is discouraged on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: your username really is "u s e r"?

Comment: I've edited the question and posted the actual code and error here. please tell me what I have to do?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the file along with the file address bar.

Answer (score 3):

Put the *.csv file in the root of the project, and then run the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv("news.csv")
```

You should avoid any problem regarding wrong paths, slashes/backslashes and/or empty chars, and it should work regardless the operative system which seems to be windows in your case.

Comment: Thank you .you were right. I got it by moving it into root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Start with rename your folders, replace spaces to '_' then try to read your file again.